# AWS: Is my VPC isolated from other clients/accounts

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

When I create a EC2 instance it gets a private IP address. I'm wondering if this address is from the subnet shared with other EC2 instances of other AWS clients.

Would it be possible for other EC2 instances of other people to connect to my EC2 instance's services via its private IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my VPC isolated from other clients/accounts?

In short: Yes.

You get your *own network* that is logically separated from from the other AWS customers and whatever (RFC1918 or other) ip-address range you decide on using, within that VPC you don't share ip-addresses with anybody else. See [this introduction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-intro/gsg-aws-compute-network.html).

> Would it be possible for other EC2 instances of other people to connect to my EC2 instance's services via its private IP?

Yes, but you have to configure that first. Amazon calls that [VPC peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html).